# Extending an interface and class to support custom properties

Tags: typescript

I want to extend this `interface` to add some custom properties:

```
interface SwiperSlideProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {}
```

which I think I've adequately done here:

```
export interface EmfSwiperSlideProps extends SwiperSlideProps {
  pin: number
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to extend this `class`:

```
declare const SwiperSlide: React.VoidFunctionComponent<SwiperSlideProps>;
```

so that I can accept the new properties and do some new work. I tried this:

```
export class EmfSwiperSlide<T extends EmfSwiperSlideProps> extends SwiperSlide<T> { }
```

but I'm getting the error:

> Type 'VoidFunctionComponent' is not a constructor function type.

I think I understand the error, such that the original class inherits from `VoidFunctionComponent`, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I am not familiar with react, but anyway extending a framework types, interfaces, and classes is not a good practice unless the framework clearly states that you can do so, otherwise an update can cause you hell

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.